# Для чего нужны геттеры и сеттеры?

Tags: javascript

Никак не могу понять для чего применять геттеры и сеттеры. Понятно, что сеттеры задают значение, а геттеры для получение, но главный вопрос - где и для чего это применять? Можете объяснить человеческим языком

Comment: При get можно возвращать измененной значение или совершать еще какое событие, к примеру у тебя может быть приватное поле в каком то формате, а через группу get можно получать в различных форматах. Так же и c set можно к примеру добавить проверки и вызывать исключения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andrey правильно сказал, но также у них есть ещё одна практическая особенность. При их правильном подходе, и использовании `private` для полей. Мы точно можем сказать, что значения задаются через **set** и получается через **get**. А значит если у нас ошибки в коде, их намного легче отлаживать, поскольку мы точно знаем что значения задаются только через них, нам не надо копатся в другом коде